# In Angular, is there a way to set a local var and constrain the scope to within some html?

Tags: angularjs

I want to do something like the following:

```
<div ng-init="name='john'">
  {{name}}
</div>
<div ng-init="name="jane'">
  {{name}}
</div>
```

I'd like this to print

```
john
jane
```

But what it will print instead is

```
jane
jane
```

I understand that in this toy example, I could just put the names into an array and use an ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="name in ['john','jane']">
  {{name}}
</div>
```

But I have slightly different html for each value but it's close enough that I'd like to be able to copy and paste without having to retype the same value over and over again.

Comment: Create a custom directive (or component) instead that use attribute bindings

Comment: Or instantiate a controller for each `<div>`. For more information, see [AngularJS Deceloper Guide - Scope Hierarchiies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-hierarchies).

Comment: The `ng-init` directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`. For more information, see [AngularJS ng-init Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of assigning name to another variable and use it , as scope value of name changes where ever it is used

```
<div ng-init="name= test ='john'">
  {{test}}
</div>
<div ng-init="name='jane'">
  {{name}}
</div>
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/erBxzG

**Option 2:**

Make every value to name array and use its index to display on UI

```
<div ng-init="name.push('john')">
  {{name[0]}}
</div>
<div ng-init="name.push('jane')">
  {{name[1]}}
</div>
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QrGYGK

Comment: The `ng-init` directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`. For more information, see [AngularJS ng-init Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).